# How can I show relationships between views in Visio database diagrams?

Tags: visio, database-design

I'm using a set of views for the data access layer of our primary web application, and need to document these views.  Logically the views mirror the underlying tables, meaning they have similar relationships to the tables.  (It's a bit more complex, since the views are pulling data from 3 databases...)

So I opened up Visio and reverse engineered the views in question into the diagram, but the problem now is that Visio won't let me add relationships to views.

Is there any way around that limitation so that I can model these views as if they were actually tables?

Or is there an easy way to "convert" each view to a table?  (I could do it manually, but that's a lot of boring typing for all the properties...)

Answer (score 1):

Have you succeeded in this? I need to document data layer based on related views, but in addition to the problem related to relations there is another one: when model is refreshed the tables in the drawings update nicely but all chenged views disappear from the drawing. The model is updated, i.e. if I drag the views back on canvas the content is updated. But still I don't want to rebuild the whole picture every time a small update is done on the DB...

Comment: Unfortunately no, I ended up just manually creating tables and filling in the columns.  :(